# what is word used to describe that "meaning has lost from originality"

Tags: american-english

I remember that many words on time get separated out from its actual meaning and people start using it for random cases to express different emotions or cases.

There is word that describes this process/behavior, what is that word.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about [semantic change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change#Types_of_semantic_change), which encompasses many different kinds of shifts.

For instance, one form would be *meoisis*, which describes how the meaning of a word becomes weaker contextually; an example from Wikipedia is that *astound* changed from "strike with thunder" to "surpise strongly".